# Always open PDFs at 100 %?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

Is it possible to configure adobe viewer to always open pdf documents at size 100 %? Now it opens documents at about 160 % for no appparent reason.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have edited the zoom in the preferences.

To set a default-zoom go to:

1. Edit --> Preferences
2. Choose the Tab `Page Display`

[image]

4. Now change the Zoom. You can edit the Zoom to whatever you want. For you 100% of course.
5. Click on the OK button
6. Exit Adobe Reader

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Preferences-> Page Display